# Generalization of the Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a generalization of the [Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem) for nets of measures? I do not find any related literature. Take a sequence of bounded measures on a sigma-field and consider a subnet of this sequence. Suppose the subnet is convergent in the sense of Vitali-Hahn-Saks. Is the limit sigma-additive?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true.

We'll think about $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra. Consider the sequence $(\delta_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $\delta_n$ is a point mass at $n$. The set of *finitely additive* (but not necessarily $\sigma$-additive) probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$ is weak${}^*$ compact, so the sequence has a subnet $(\delta_{n_\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ which converges, say, to $\sigma.$

Weak${}^*$ convergence tells us precisely that $\lim_\alpha \delta_{n_\alpha}(X) = \sigma(X)$ for all measurable $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. In particular, $\sigma(\{m\}) = 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma(\mathbb{N}) = 1$, implying that $\sigma$ is not countably additive.

For more on finitely additive measures and the weak${}^*$ topology, you can check out *Linear Operators Part I: General Theory* by Dunford and Schwartz.